# ambiguous operator<< for templated overload

Tags: templates, c++11, operator-overloading, pretty-print, iterable

Following code is my first C++11 attempt at pretty printing iterable containers. It uses the function template default parameter feature.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void print(std::ostream &o, T const &t) { o<< t; }

void print(std::ostream &o, std::string const &s){ o<< '"'<< s<< '"'; }

template <typename K, typename V>
void print(std::ostream &o, std::pair<K, V> const &p)
{
  o<< '{'; print(o, p.first);
  o<< ": "; print(o, p.second);
  o<< '}';
}

template <typename C, typename I= typename C::const_iterator>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &o, C const &c)
{
  o<< '[';
  if(c.empty()) return o<< ']';
  I b= c.begin(), e= c.end(); -- e;
  for(; b!= e; ++ b)
  {
    print(o, *b);
    o<< ", ";
  }
  print(o, *b);
  return o<< ']';
}
```

It works fine on containers, container of containers etc. With one exception:

```
std::cout<< std::string("wtf");
```

Compilation with g++4.7/8 breaks saying `ambiguous operator<<`.

Is there any fix for this code to avoid the ambiguity?

Comment: Since `std::string` has a `const_iterator`, your `operator<<` template is a match.

Comment: @VaughnCato yes, I'd like std::basic_string<char, allocator> overload to be preferred if possible.

Comment: You could use an `enable_if` to disable your overload when `C` is a string.

Comment: OT, but you may use `auto b = c.begin()` instead of `I b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::enable_if` to disable your overload in the case of a string:

```
template <typename C, typename I= typename C::const_iterator>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<C,std::string>::value,std::ostream>::type &
  operator<< (std::ostream &o, C const &c)
{
  o<< '[';
  if(c.empty()) return o<< ']';
  I b= c.begin(), e= c.end(); -- e;
  for(; b!= e; ++ b)
  {
    print(o, *b);
    o<< ", ";
  }
  print(o, *b);
  return o<< ']';
}
```

or to do it more generically:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_string : std::false_type {};

template <typename Char,typename Allocator>
struct is_string<std::basic_string<Char,Allocator> > : std::true_type {};

template <typename C, typename I= typename C::const_iterator>
typename std::enable_if<!is_string<C>::value,std::ostream>::type &
  operator<< (std::ostream &o, C const &c)
{
  o<< '[';
  if(c.empty()) return o<< ']';
  I b= c.begin(), e= c.end(); -- e;
  for(; b!= e; ++ b)
  {
    print(o, *b);
    o<< ", ";
  }
  print(o, *b);
  return o<< ']';
}
```

Comment: good call, I wanted to do it without enable_ifs (hence default parameter) but you gave the correct answer anyway.